# Adding new sheet to 2000 xlsx files - Openpyxl is very slow

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a python script that is working. My only issue is how slow it is. I have 2000 files and each one is taking near a minute to add a new worksheet tab.

Is my code missing something? I feel like I may be doing something wrong. Or should I be using a different library?

Here is my script:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pathlib import Path

my_path = "C:\\Desktop\\test"

for filename in Path(my_path).glob('*.xlsx'):
    try:
        wb = load_workbook(filename)
        wb.create_sheet("Export")
        wb.save(filename)
        wb.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:    
        wb = None
```

Comment: Why do you need the `finally` block?

Comment: I was just attempting to "empty" the wb variable

Comment: Read [openpyxl - performance](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance.html)

Comment: @stovfl  Thanks for the link. That info is why I was wondering if there was a better library to use.

Comment: How big are the files? What you're doing requires all existing data to loaded into memory and saved to disk.

Comment: @CharlieClark - The files are between 4 and 7 MBs each.

Comment: Depending on the details of the workbooks and your computer I would expect most workbooks to take about 10s to load.